# React app goes blank when i send a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, xml

I'm trying to make a smart house app in which the user can add rooms to his house etc...
whenever i try to send a function that adds a new object (room) to a hook of objects (in an array) by props to a component, and a different component runs a map on the hooked array to display all of the objects, my entire react app goes entirely white (blank)
This is my code:

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from 'react';
import AddButton from './components/AddButton';
import AddRoom from './components/AddRoom';
import RoomsList from './components/RoomsList';

function App() {
  class Room {
    constructor(roomname, roomcolor) {
      this.roomname = roomname;
      this.roomcolor = roomcolor;
      /*add room color*/

    }}
  const [RoomsList, setRoomsList] = useState();
  let addRoomFunc = (roomname, roomcolor) => {
    let temp = new Room(roomname, roomcolor);
    if (roomname.length<=1) { return window.alert("Error") }
    else {setRoomsList(...RoomsList, temp) }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Smart House</h1>
      <RoomsList roomslist={RoomsList}/>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AddButton></AddButton>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/AddRoom" element={<AddRoom addroomfunc={addRoomFunc}/>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**AddRoom.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function AddRoom(props) {
  const [RoomName, setRoomName] = useState();
  const [RoomColor, setRoomColor] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "27%",
          width: "229px",
          height: "40px",
          right: "42.5%",
        }}
      >
        <option disabled selected="true">
          Select
        </option>
        <option>Kitchen</option>
        <option>Bedroom</option>
        <option>Bathroom</option>
      </select>

      <input
        onClick={(element) => {
          setRoomName(element.target.value);
        }}
        maxLength={5}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "33%",
          width: "220px",
          height: "40px",
          right: "42.5%",
        }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
      ></input>
      <input
        onClick={(element) => {
          setRoomColor(element.target.value);
        }}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "40%",
          width: "220px",
          height: "40px",
          right: "42.5%",
        }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Color"
      ></input>
      <Link to="/">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            {
              props.addRoomFunc(RoomName, RoomColor);
            }
          }}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: "47%",
            width: "228px",
            height: "40px",
            right: "42.5%",
          }}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**RoomsList.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import AddRoom from "./AddRoom";
import App from "../App";

export default function RoomsList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.roomslist.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{value.name}</h1>
            <h1>{value.color}</h1>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: notice there are 3 components:  App.js (the main)    AddRoom.jsx and  RoomsList.jsx

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
setRoomsList(...RoomsList, temp)
```

to:

```
setRoomsList([...RoomsList, temp])
```

Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: changed it. nothing happens, same old blank page. and yes i do get errors but they are too long to copy into here

Comment: I think we will need the errors to know what's wrong, trying pasting them into a paste bin https://pastebin.com/ and update your question with them :)

Comment: it was solvedty anyway